# Matplotlib discrete colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a discrete colorbar for a scatterplot in matplotlib

I have my x, y data and for each point an integer tag value which I want to be represented with a unique colour, e.g.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=tag)
```

typically tag will be an integer ranging from 0-20, but the exact range may change

so far I have just used the default settings, e.g.

```
plt.colorbar()
```

which gives a continuous range of colours. Ideally i would like a set of n discrete colours (n=20 in this example). Even better would be to get a tag value of 0 to produce a gray colour and 1-20 be colourful.

I have found some 'cookbook' scripts but they are very complicated and I cannot think they are the right way to solve a seemingly simple problem

Comment: does [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html) or [this](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/ColormapTransformations) help?

Comment: thanks for links but the 2nd example is what I mean about hugely overcomplicated means to perform a (seemingly) trivial task - 1st link is useful

Comment: I found this link very helpful in discretizing an existing colormap: https://gist.github.com/jakevdp/91077b0cae40f8f8244a

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can create a custom discrete colorbar quite easily by using a BoundaryNorm as normalizer for your scatter. The quirky bit (in my method) is making 0 showup as grey.

For images i often use the cmap.set_bad() and convert my data to a numpy masked array. That would be much easier to make 0 grey, but i couldnt get this to work with the scatter or the custom cmap.

As an alternative you can make your own cmap from scratch, or read-out an existing one and override just some specific entries.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))  # setup the plot

x = np.random.rand(20)  # define the data
y = np.random.rand(20)  # define the data
tag = np.random.randint(0, 20, 20)
tag[10:12] = 0  # make sure there are some 0 values to show up as grey

cmap = plt.cm.jet  # define the colormap
# extract all colors from the .jet map
cmaplist = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
# force the first color entry to be grey
cmaplist[0] = (.5, .5, .5, 1.0)

# create the new map
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'Custom cmap', cmaplist, cmap.N)

# define the bins and normalize
bounds = np.linspace(0, 20, 21)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# make the scatter
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c=tag, s=np.random.randint(100, 500, 20),
                  cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

# create a second axes for the colorbar
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
cb = plt.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
    spacing='proportional', ticks=bounds, boundaries=bounds, format='%1i')

ax.set_title('Well defined discrete colors')
ax2.set_ylabel('Very custom cbar [-]', size=12)
```

[image]

I personally think that with 20 different colors its a bit hard to read the specific value, but thats up to you of course.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is allowed, but could you look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766062/how-to-determine-the-colours-when-using-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow)?

Comment: `plt.colorbar.ColorbarBase` throws Error. Use `mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase`

Comment: Thank you for this answer, really miss it from the doc. I tried to transpose it for windroses of percentiles and I had a bug with color mapping. It is a different use case, but it may suggest that it is `N-1` in `cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom cmap', cmaplist, cmap.N-1)`. If not colors are not equally distributed within bins and you have a fence barrier problem.

Comment: Here is the code to reproduce a equally distributed mapping: `q=np.arange(0.0, 1.01, 0.1)
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('jet')
cmaplist = [cmap(x) for x in q]
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom cmap', cmaplist, len(q)-1)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(q, cmap.N)`

Comment: I'm not sure about the `N-1`, you maybe right but I can't replicate it with my example. You might avoid the `LinearSegmentedColormap` (and it's `N` argument) by using a `ListedColormap`. The docs have improved a lot since '13, see for example:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar

Comment: How do you do this if you dont want numbers 0-20, but strings?

Comment: @SatyapriyaKrishna, you would still need a value to map it to a color (that's the `bounds`). But you can override the ticklabels with a string by using `cb.set_ticklabels(...)`, and possibly first use `cb.get_ticklabels(...)` for mapping the original values to a string.

Comment: never mind actually, I went with legends instead.

Answer (score 90):

You could follow [this example below](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/poormans_contour.html) or the [newly added example in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html?highlight=contour_demo)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Use a pcolor or imshow with a custom colormap to make a contour plot.

Since this example was initially written, a proper contour routine was
added to matplotlib - see contour_demo.py and
http://matplotlib.sf.net/matplotlib.pylab.html#-contour.
"""

from pylab import *


delta = 0.01
x = arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = Z2 - Z1 # difference of Gaussians

cmap = cm.get_cmap('PiYG', 11)    # 11 discrete colors

im = imshow(Z, cmap=cmap, interpolation='bilinear',
            vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())
axis('off')
colorbar()

show()
```

which produces the following image:

[image: poormans_contour]

Comment: cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 20) then scatter(x,y,c=tags,cmap=cmap) gets me part way there - its very difficult to find useful documentation for matplotlib

Answer (score 77):

The above answers are good, except they don't have proper tick placement on the colorbar. I like having the ticks in the middle of the color so that the number -> color mapping is more clear. You can solve this problem by changing the limits of the matshow call:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def discrete_matshow(data):
    # get discrete colormap
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdBu', np.max(data) - np.min(data) + 1)
    # set limits .5 outside true range
    mat = plt.matshow(data, cmap=cmap, vmin=np.min(data) - 0.5, 
                      vmax=np.max(data) + 0.5)
    # tell the colorbar to tick at integers
    cax = plt.colorbar(mat, ticks=np.arange(np.min(data), np.max(data) + 1))

# generate data
a = np.random.randint(1, 9, size=(10, 10))
discrete_matshow(a)
```

[image: example of discrete colorbar]

Comment: I agree that placing the tick in the middle of the corresponding color is very helpful when looking at discrete data. Your second method is correct. However, your first method is, in general, _wrong_: you are labeling the ticks with values that are inconsistent with their placement on the colorbar. `set_ticklabels(...)` should only be used to control the label formatting (e.g. decimal number, etc.). If the data is truly discrete, you may not notice any problems. If there is noise in the system (e.g. 2 -> 1.9), this inconsistent labeling will result in a misleading and incorrect colorbar.

Comment: E., I think you are right that changing the limits is the superior solution so I removed the other one-- though neither would handle "noise" well. Some adjustments would be needed for handling continuous data.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the legend on the right with string values (e.g. forest, urban) instead of values from 1 to 8?

Comment: This works! Though I think using `'tab20'` instead of `'RdBu'` works better for me to distinguish the colors.

Answer (score 44):

To set a values above or below the range of the colormap, you'll want to use the `set_over` and `set_under` methods of the colormap.  If you want to flag a particular value, mask it (i.e. create a masked array), and use the `set_bad` method.  (Have a look at the documentation for the base colormap class: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap )

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 30))
z = z * 20 + 0.1

# Set some values in z to 0...
z[:5] = 0

cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet', 20)
cmap.set_under('gray')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100, cmap=cmap, vmin=0.1, vmax=z.max())
fig.colorbar(cax, extend='min')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thats really good - i tried using set_under but hadn't included vmin so i don't think it was doing anything

Comment: excellent. This allows you to use the built-in colormaps.

Answer (score 33):

This topic is well covered already but I wanted to add something more specific : I wanted to be sure that a certain value would be mapped to that color (not to any color).

It is not complicated but as it took me some time, it might help others not lossing as much time as I did :)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# Let's design a dummy land use field
A = np.reshape([7, 2, 13, 7, 2, 2], (2, 3))
vals = np.unique(A)

# Let's also design our color mapping: 1s should be plotted in blue, 2s in red, etc...
col_dict = {1: "blue",
            2: "red",
            13: "orange",
            7: "green"}

# We create a colormar from our list of colors
cm = ListedColormap([col_dict[x] for x in col_dict.keys()])

# Let's also define the description of each category : 1 (blue) is Sea; 2 (red) is burnt, etc... Order should be respected here ! Or using another dict maybe could help.
labels = np.array(["Sea", "City", "Sand", "Forest"])
len_lab = len(labels)

# prepare normalizer
# Prepare bins for the normalizer
norm_bins = np.sort([*col_dict.keys()]) + 0.5
norm_bins = np.insert(norm_bins, 0, np.min(norm_bins) - 1.0)
print(norm_bins)
# Make normalizer and formatter
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(norm_bins, len_lab, clip=True)
fmt = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: labels[norm(x)])

# Plot our figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(A, cmap=cm, norm=norm)

diff = norm_bins[1:] - norm_bins[:-1]
tickz = norm_bins[:-1] + diff / 2
cb = fig.colorbar(im, format=fmt, ticks=tickz)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Was trying to replicate this, however the code does not run because 'tmp' is undefined. Also unclear what 'pos' is in the lambda function. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeLiu Indeed you were write ! I did a copy/paste mistake and it is now fxed ! The snippet of code is now running !

Regarding `pos` I am not entirely sure of why it is here but it is requested by the FuncFormatter()... Maybe someone else can enlighten us about it !

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, but unfortunately I think there is a bug -- the 7s should be green but are orange, and the 13s should be orange but are green.

Answer (score 10):

I have been investigating these ideas and here is my five cents worth. It avoids calling `BoundaryNorm` as well as specifying `norm` as an argument to `scatter` and `colorbar`. However I have found no way of eliminating the rather long-winded call to `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list`.

Some background is that matplotlib provides so-called qualitative colormaps, intended to use with discrete data. `Set1`, e.g., has 9 easily distinguishable colors, and `tab20` could be used for 20 colors. With these maps it could be natural to use their first n colors to color scatter plots with n categories, as the following example does. The example also produces a colorbar with n discrete colors approprately labelled.

```
import matplotlib, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 5
from_list = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list
cm = from_list(None, plt.cm.Set1(range(0,n)), n)
x = np.arange(99)
y = x % 11
z = x % n
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap=cm)
plt.clim(-0.5, n-0.5)
cb = plt.colorbar(ticks=range(0,n), label='Group')
cb.ax.tick_params(length=0)
```

which produces the image below. The `n` in the call to `Set1` specifies
the first `n` colors of that colormap, and the last `n` in the call to `from_list`
specifies to construct a map with `n` colors (the default being 256). In order to set `cm` as the default colormap with `plt.set_cmap`, I found it to be necessary to give it a name and register it, viz:

```
cm = from_list('Set15', plt.cm.Set1(range(0,n)), n)
plt.cm.register_cmap(None, cm)
plt.set_cmap(cm)
...
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
```

[image: scatterplot with disrete colors]

Comment: Short and effective! Perfect!

Comment: Will it work for images as well?

Answer (score 1):

@Enzoupi's answer has a lot of good stuff in it. I broke it down a bit to see what's what. This is my annotated version. All credit goes to them.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# Let's design a dummy land use field
A = np.reshape([7, 2, 13, 7, 2, 2], (2, 3))

# Let's also design our color mapping: 1s should be plotted in blue, 2s in red, etc...
col_dict = {1: "blue",
            2: "red",
            13: "orange",
            7: "green"}

# We create a colormar from our list of colors
cm = ListedColormap(colors=list(col_dict.values()))

# Note the colormap `cm` has no information as to the values we want each color
# to represent... to do that, we have to normalize the image.
# We create bins by adding 0.5 to each value (this assumes no two values are
# less than 0.5 apart)
norm_bins = np.sort([*col_dict.keys()]) + 0.5
# We must also add a bin at the bottom; doesn't matter really where as long as
# it's below the minimum value. This is because `BoundaryNorm` needs bins on
# either side of a value to map that value to a particular color.
norm_bins = np.insert(norm_bins, 0, np.min(norm_bins) - 1.0)  # add one below the minimum
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(norm_bins, len(col_dict), clip=True)

# Let's also define the description of each category : 1 (blue) is Sea; 2 (red) is burnt, etc...
# Order should be respected here ! Or using another dict maybe could help.
labels = ["Sea", "City", "Sand", "Forest"]

# We need a tick formatter that takes the value `x` and maps it to a label.
# We use the normalizer we created to take land use values and convert to the
# color index, and then use that to pick from our label list.
fmt = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: labels[norm(x)])

# But, as-is, the ticks will be at the boundary limits, which will appear to
# show incorrect labels. So we must also put the ticks at the center of each bin
# in the normalizer.
diff = norm_bins[1:] - norm_bins[:-1]
ticks = norm_bins[:-1] + diff / 2

# So in summary:
# Plot `A` using a list of colors `cm`. Normalize the values in `A` using `norm`
# (so that discontinous values map to the correct colors)
im = plt.imshow(A, cmap=cm, norm=norm)
# Add a colorbar which positions ticks at the center of each color band and
# formats them so they're labeled according to the meaning of the value.
plt.colorbar(im, format=fmt, ticks=ticks)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to look at [colors.ListedColormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap) to generate your colormap, or if you just need a static colormap I've been working on [an app](https://github.com/ccoughlin/ColormapCreator) that might help.

Comment: that looks cool, possibly overkill for my needs - could you suggest a way of tagging a gray value onto an existing colormap? so that 0 values come out gray and the others come out as colours?

Comment: @Hiett what about generating an RGB array color_list based on your y values and passing that to ListedColormap?  You can tag a value with color_list[y==value_to_tag] = gray_color.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was similar, but had some additional requirements:

1. Should map a list of arbitrary integers to arbitrary colors.
2. Should not assume that the integers are contiguous, sorted, or represented in the data.

Thanks to @Enzoupi for providing a starting point, which I've refactored to make more reusable and debugged to correctly map colors to integers.

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import pylab as plt


class Label:
    def __init__(self, integer, color, label):
        self.integer = integer
        self.color = color
        self.label = label


class DiscreteColormapGenerator:
    def __init__(self, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.labels.sort(key=lambda x: x.integer)

    def get_colormap(self):
        return mpl.colors.ListedColormap([l.color for l in self.labels])

    def get_normalizer(self):
        bins = [l.integer for l in self.labels]
        bins = [self.labels[0].integer - 1] + bins + [self.labels[-1].integer + 1]
        bins = np.array(bins[0:-1] + bins[1:]).reshape(2, -1).mean(0)
        return mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bins, len(self.labels), clip=True)

    def get_legend_patches(self):
        return [mpl.patches.Patch(color=l.color, label=l.label) for l in labels]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    labels = [
        Label(1, "blue", "Sea"),
        Label(2, "red", "City"),
        Label(13, "orange", "Sand"),
        Label(7, "green", "Forest"),
    ]

    cmpr = DiscreteColormapGenerator(labels)
    cmpr.get_normalizer()

    A = np.reshape([7, 2, 13, 7, 2, 2], (2, 3))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(A, cmap=cmpr.get_colormap(), norm=cmpr.get_normalizer())
    fig.legend(handles=cmpr.get_legend_patches())
    plt.show()
```