# Defining a binary matplotlib colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the `matplotlib.imshow` to plot a boolean 2d array and I'd like to be able to pick the two colours (one for `true` and one for `false`). It seems that this argument should be passed as a colormap to `imshow` but in my case it seems a bit of an overkill as I don't need continuous and, more important, I don't know how to define a custom colormap (the matplotlib doc hasn't helped me with that).

Comment: can you link to the doc that you were reading and explain what wasn't clear?

Comment: You can make color maps with a discrete number of steps, just use 2 for binary data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

# Color for False and True
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['red', 'green'])

plt.imshow([True, False], [False, True]], cmap=cmap)
```

[image: []

Comment: SpongeBob narrator: "Six years later..."

Comment: Indeed, 6years since I asked that. Finally I can close this and move on with my life =)