# Python NetworkX — set node color automatically based on a list of values

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I generated a graph with `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx  
s = 5
G = nx.grid_graph(dim=[s,s])
nodes = list(G.nodes)
edges = list(G.edges)
p = []
for i in range(0, s):
    for j in range(0, s):
        p.append([i,j])
for i in range(0, len(nodes)):
    G.nodes[nodes[i]]['pos'] = p[i]

pos = {}
for i in range(0, len(nodes)):
        pos[nodes[i]] = p[i]

nx.draw(G, pos)
```

[image]

Now I would like to assign a value to each node between `0` and `4`

```
from random import randint
val = []
for i in range(0, len(G.nodes())):
    val.append(randint(0,4))
```

And I would like to assign the color to each node base on the `val` list and plot something like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910766/python-networkx-set-node-color-automatically-based-on-number-of-attribute-opt)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a node property, you can use:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, val, 'val')
```

Networkx draw calls down to [draw_networkx_nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes), this takes a cmap and color list, so all you would have to do would be something like:

```
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'val'), vmin=0, vmax=4, cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('rainbow'))
```

Comment: it is not a property of a node given `val`

Comment: I've edited the answer to use node attributes.  Is that what you meant for a node property?

Comment: @ComplexGates isn't `nx.set_node_attributes(G, val, 'val')` assigning all the values of the list to each node here?  I found that setting `node_color = val` was sufficient

Answer (score 8):

`networkx.draw` has the [node_color, vmin, vmax and cmap](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx) parameters:

*cmap (Matplotlib colormap, optional (default=None)) – Colormap for mapping intensities of nodes*

*vmin,vmax (float, optional (default=None)) – Minimum and maximum for node colormap scaling*

*node_color (color string, or array of floats, (default=’#1f78b4’)) – Node color. Can be a single color format string, or a sequence of colors with the same length as nodelist. If numeric values are specified they will be mapped to colors using the cmap and vmin,vmax parameters. See matplotlib.scatter for more details.*

You can write a list in it so your nodes will be colored (for example):

```
colors = [i/len(G.nodes) for i in range(len(G.nodes))]
...
...
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=colors)
```

[image]

Comment: but it is not a property of a node given `val`

Comment: It is just an example. You can send your `val` list as this parameter and set vmin/vmax parameters. cmap is optional, you can not to set it.