# Add Color to nodes based on nodes values

Tags: python, networkx

I am using networkx to visualize my data. here is my data:

Nodes: 1234, 3243, 4234, 4324, 4342, 3131, 8798

value -1, 1, 0.3, 1.35, -0.05, -0.5, 0.75

How can I assign a color to the nodes based their value? I want to say something like if the node values is less than 0 make my nodes blue, if it is above 0 but less than 1 assign red to them and for the nodes above 1 assign green to the nodes?

Thank you

Comment: [Graph Optimization with NetworkX in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/networkx-python-graph-tutorial) might offer some insight.  There's a section on visualization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python NetworkX — set node color automatically based on a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537065/python-networkx-set-node-color-automatically-based-on-a-list-of-values)