# To make a graph using Networkx after spectral clustering on moons dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cluster-analysis, networkx

I have generated moons dataset with 20 points and done spectral clustering on it. I want to form a graph using nearest neighbours = 3 with the help of Networkx. Where data points are the nodes and the affinity matrix generated after clustering is the weight over the edges between different nodes. I also need help in changing the colour and shape of the nodes of the two clusters so as to differentiate nodes of one cluster from another. Code is given below. An output image is given below. I just want to make a graph between the nodes of my output image using nearest neighbour=3.

```
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import sklearn.metrics as sm
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=20)
print(X)
print(y)
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], marker='o', facecolors='none', edgecolor='r')
clustering=SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,
       assign_labels='kmeans',affinity='rbf',gamma=50, degree=3,
         random_state=0)
y_predict=clustering.fit_predict(X)
y_predict
clustering.labels_
clustering.affinity_matrix_
for i in range(0, y_predict.shape[0]):
    if y[i]==0 and y_predict[i]==0 :
        c1 = pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1],c='b',
    marker='+')
    elif y[i]==1 and y_predict[i]==0:
        c2 = pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1], facecolors='none', edgecolor='b',
    marker='o')
    elif y[i]==0 and y_predict[i]==1:
        c3=pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1],c='r',
    marker='+')
    elif y[i]==1 and y_predict[i]==1:
        c4=pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1], facecolors='none', edgecolor='r',
    marker='o')
pl.show()
```

[Image of the clustering of moons dataset is given below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsJhO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of the answer to your previous question, this is what you asked for I believe.

[image: updated_moon_fig]

Since the values in the affinity matrix are all between 0 and 1 but of very different relative magnitudes, I used `-10 / log(weight)` as the edge width.

```
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import sklearn.metrics as sm
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import math
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=20)
print(X)
print(y)
#plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], marker='o', facecolors='none', edgecolor='r')
pl.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
clustering=SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,
       assign_labels='kmeans',affinity='rbf',gamma=50, degree=3,
         random_state=0)
y_predict=clustering.fit_predict(X)
y_predict
clustering.labels_
clustering.affinity_matrix_
for i in range(0, y_predict.shape[0]):
    if y[i]==0 and y_predict[i]==0 :
        c1 = pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1],c='b',
    marker='+')
    elif y[i]==1 and y_predict[i]==0:
        c2 = pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1], facecolors='none', edgecolor='b',
    marker='o')
    elif y[i]==0 and y_predict[i]==1:
        c3=pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1],c='r',
    marker='+')
    elif y[i]==1 and y_predict[i]==1:
        c4=pl.scatter(X[i,0],X[i,1], facecolors='none', edgecolor='r',
    marker='o')
        
for i in range(0, len(X)):
  affinity_list = clustering.affinity_matrix_[i]
  affinity_list[i] = 0 # in case we don't want to consider the node as it's own neighbour
  nearest_neighbors_indices = np.argpartition(clustering.affinity_matrix_[i], -k)[-k:]
  for j in nearest_neighbors_indices:
    G.add_edge(tuple(X[i]), tuple(X[j]), weight = clustering.affinity_matrix_[i][j])

weights = [-10/math.log(edge[-1]['weight']) for edge in G.edges.data()]
# Draw Graph
pos = {node_name: node_name for node_name in G.nodes}
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=weights)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But in your output figure, I am not able to see the edges properly that are connecting the nodes. The connection between the nearest neighbour nodes is not clear and also I don't want to have a red circle in the upper part of the moons around '+' sign@Frodnar

Comment: Fair enough, @Ytt.  I updated the figure and code based on your feedback.  I made the edge width proportional to `-10 / log(weight)`.  I also enlarged the figure to show more detail.  If the answer looks good, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you @Frodnar for your great help. I exactly wanted this figure.

Comment: I just wanted one small help. Can this graph be created using KMeans clustering?. An answer for this will be really appreciated.@Frodnar

Comment: @Ytt instead of writing a comment to say "thank you", use the upvote button, and if it's the best answer which correctly answers your question, mark the answer as correct, so that others that have the same question as you might easily find the answer in the future. Please, check this link with a 1-minute read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
 
As a side note... Yes, you could use the KMeans method available in the SciKit Clustering package, instead of SpectralClustering, and it should work just fine. I recommend trying that yourself and seeing if it actually works.