# Pythonic way to simulate d3js color scale behaviour

Tags: python, d3.js

In D3js we can map any word to a color simply by defining color scale limit. D3js scaling system manage the way to map any word into the scale for you.
It seems to be much more complicated in python. Am I missing something ?

Is there a simple way in Python to get a color for a given string ?

Comment: Please specify more precisely, WHAT d3js actually does or at least link some source (code)

Comment: [You can use color bars from matplotlib, and choose a set of discrete colors, as shown in the following answer from stack overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar)

Comment: A dict of colour names and RGB values?