# How to perform custom sort for both x- and y-axes on indexed DataFrame for heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, seaborn, categorical-data

This question gives the solution to sort the y-axis: [Data order in seaborn heatmap from pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694368/data-order-in-seaborn-heatmap-from-pivot)
**But how to perform custom sort for both x- and y-axes?**

Without custom sort, we see the order:

- **x-axis**: phone, tv
- **y-axis**: apple, google, samsung

Code:

```
lol = [['apple', 'phone', 10], ['samsung', 'tv', 20], ['apple', 'tv', 5], ['google', 'tv', 8], ['google', 'phone', 9], ['samsung', 'phone', 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lol)
df = df.rename(columns={0:'brand', 1:'product', 2:'count'})
df = df.pivot('brand', 'product', 'count')
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

[out]:

[image]

If I need to sort the y-axis to show the order `samsung, apple, google`, I could do:

```
lol = [['apple', 'phone', 10], ['samsung', 'tv', 20], ['apple', 'tv', 5], ['google', 'tv', 8], ['google', 'phone', 9], ['samsung', 'phone', 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lol)
df = df.rename(columns={0:'brand', 1:'product', 2:'count'})
df = df.pivot('brand', 'product', 'count')

df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index, categories= ["samsung", "apple", "google"])
df.sortlevel(level=0, inplace=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

[out]:

[image]

**But how to perform custom sort for both x- and y-axes?**, e.g.

- **y-axis** to show the order `samsung, apple, google`
- **x-axis** to show the order `tv, phone` (not just reversing the order)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
a = ['samsung', 'apple', 'google']
b = ['tv','phone']

df = df.pivot('brand', 'product', 'count')
df = df.reindex(index=a, columns=b)
print (df)
product  tv  phone
brand             
samsung  20      3
apple     5     10
google    8      9
```

Or [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
df['brand'] = df['brand'].astype('category', categories=a, ordered=True)
df['product'] = df['product'].astype('category', categories=b, ordered=True)

df = df.pivot('brand', 'product', 'count')
print (df)
product  tv  phone
brand             
samsung  20      3
apple     5     10
google    8      9
```

---

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```