# How to make visual graph with 'matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap' for 6 features

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am using a support vector machine classifier and would like to visualize my results. I have 6 features that I would like to graph however, my code is only set up for 2 features. I cant seem to edit the code for it to graph all 6 features.

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(X1.shape)


plt.contourf(X1, X2, Z, alpha = 0.45, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green','blue')))

plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green', 'blue'))(i), label = j)

plt.title('Classification Data Set Name Here')
plt.xlabel('Feature X')
plt.ylabel('Feature Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Discrete colormaps https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib discrete colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar)

Comment: This is s standard `matplotlib` question (added), and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `svm` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).