# Matplotlib - Adding a categorical colorbar that matches the color plotted on a scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

I'm trying to generate a scatter plot where each point has an associated color and then to generate a colorbar with those same colors. However, when I try to generate the plot, the scatter plot has the correct colors, but they do not match the actual color bar.

```
x = embedding[:,0]
y= embedding[:,1]

fig, ax=plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(x, y, c=color_list, s=1)
plt.setp(ax, xticks=[], yticks=[])
cbar = plt.colorbar(boundaries=np.arange(0.5, df_meta['GCT-ap'].value_counts().count()+0.5))
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(28))
cbar.set_ticklabels(df_meta['GCT-ap'].unique().tolist())
```

`color_list` is a list of hex colors for every point:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gVS7.png)

I want to take those same colors and use it to make a color bar with the matching ticklabels, which is contained in `df_meta['GCT-ap']:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3zCr.png)

The problem is that the colorbar color does not match the actual scatter plot colors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD0LP.png)

Comment: I think this is covered a few ways in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar

Comment: Please do not use screenshot of the dataframe, instead, please provide mockup data, in particular check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)