# Plotting scatter plot of pandas dataframe with both categorical and numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a scatter plot of the following type of pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['RH1', 1, 3], ['RH2', 0, 3], ['RH3', 2, 0], ['RH4', 1, 2], columns=['name', 'A', 'B'])
```

The final plot should have "name" column as Y axis and "A" and "B" as X axis. And the different numerical values with different colours. something like this
[image]

I tried to plot it by looping over each row of the dataframe but I got stuck at some place and couldn't do it, the main problem I encounter is the size of both the axis. It would be really great if anyone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) your dataframe and use the values as the column for color:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['RH1', 1, 3], ['RH2', 0, 3], ['RH3', 2, 0], ['RH4', 1, 2]], columns=['name', 'A', 'B'])

df.melt(["name"]).plot(x="variable", y= "name", kind="scatter", c="value", cmap="plasma")
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

If you have a limited number of values, you can change the colormap to a [discrete colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779462/8881141) and label each color with its value. Alternatively, use seaborn's stripplot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame([['RH1', 1, 3], ['RH2', 0, 3], ['RH3', 2, 0], ['RH4', 1, 2]], columns=['name', 'A', 'B'])

sns.stripplot(data=df.melt(["name"]), x="variable", y= "name", hue="value", jitter=False)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I did not know about df.melt() function, it's a great function. Thank you again :)