# How can I create a legend for a cartopy and Matplotlib plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am classifying points of the earth (lon and lat coordinates) into categories based on variables for that point.
I have an array (360 x 720) (the resolution of my lat, lon grid for earth) that contains the appropriate classification for each point as a number,
there are 13 categories; a, b, c,...
and in my 360x 720 array these categories are represented as 1, 2, 3,..., 13.

I can map this via cartopy and matplotlib, but i am stuck trying to make a legend/ key that shows what category each color mapped represents, the best i can get is an unhelpful colorbar.

```
 ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) #cartopy

preplot = plt.contourf(lons, lats, Map, 17,
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = "tab20")
ax.coastlines() # cartopy
cb = plt.colorbar(preplot, orientation="horizontal")

plt.title("1901")

plt.show()
```

which gives:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxxga.png)
A map and colorbar

Sorry if this is not all the needed info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add labels for all 13 categories to your colorbar? In that case, you should set a total of 13 ticks on your colorbar (as you have 13 categories) using:

```
cb.set_ticks([i for i in range(1, 14, 1)])
```

Now, you should see a total of 13 ticks on your colorbar. However, currently the `ticklabels` are the numbers `1-13`. To change this, you can use `cb.set_ticklabels(<list_of_strings>)`. So, for example:

```
cb.set_ticklabels(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'])
```

In this case, your complete code would be:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) #cartopy

preplot = plt.contourf(lons, lats, Map, 17,
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = "tab20")
ax.coastlines() # cartopy
cb = plt.colorbar(preplot, orientation="horizontal")

# Update the colorbar ticks + labels
cb.set_ticks([i for i in range(1, 14, 1)])
cb.set_ticklabels(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'])

plt.title("1901")

plt.show()
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly thanks, I'm now struggling with trying to get a colormap for the map/ colorbar that has 13 colors in it so that everything lines up

Comment: @Morgan, would the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar) help you out? Just remember that a colormap is basically a look-up list for colors, so you could in principle just extract 13 colors from any colormap and put them into your own colormap (created using `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap`). Subsequently you will have to define proper boundaries/bins for your colormap (using `matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm`) and perform some normalisation.