# Specify color levels for matplotlib Axes.scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, scatter

If I'm doing a scatter plot with the points coloured based on magnitude, can I specify the color levels like in contour & contourf?

For example I do this:

```py
from random import randrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, t, t  = [], [], []
for x in range(10):
     y.append(randrange(30,45,1))
     x.append(randrange(50,65,1))
     t.append(randrange(0,20,1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
scats = ax.scatter(x,y,s=30,c=t, marker = 'o', cmap = "hsv")
plt.show()
```

Which produces a plot something like this:

[image]

But is there some way to add a 'levels' type argument in the scatter plot? There I could specify my levels as being [0,4,8,12,16,20] or something?

Comment: You mean like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779462/8881141)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, also you have multiple errors in your code which I fixed: You define `t` twice but don't define `y` at all, you override `x` with your loop variable, which you should instead replace with `_` which is convention in Python for variables that you will not use.

```
from random import randrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

cmap = plt.cm.hsv
bounds = [0,4,8,12,16,20]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

x, y, t  = [], [], []
for _ in range(10):
    x.append(randrange(30,45,1))
    y.append(randrange(50,65,1))
    t.append(randrange(0,20,1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
scats = ax.scatter(x,y,s=30,c=t, marker = 'o', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(scats)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you're right, I altered the code crudely before I posted and didn't realise these mistakes! Thank you for this answer :)