# Representing values on square instead of using a colour bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I have this piece of code that displays the policies for a robot. The polices are essentially colourful squares that represent a value. Right now the squares have a colour and I have placed in a colour bar to show what those colours represent. But I would like to have it so that each value that is represented by the colour of the square is on each square itself. How could I do this?

```
def show_policy(self, policy=None):
    plt.title("Policies for Robot")
    plt.imshow(self.policy)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to have text on the legend or do you want it on the image itself? If you want it on the legend this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60870122/12337195

Comment: Hi, I want it on the image itself! But thank you.

Comment: I saw the question was marked duplicate but the answer there was barely documented and not very relevant (text on square vs. box in annotations), maybe this can help you better:

```python
data = np.array([[1, 20, 40, 50],[8, 30, 1, 60],[80, 49, 19, 5]])
plt.imshow(data)
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        plt.text(j, i, value, ha="center", va="center", backgroundcolor="#FFFFFF50")

plt.colorbar()
```
I know your image is probably not a 1D array, but iteration and plt.text are the important parts here

Comment: comments don't allow newlines apparently :/