# Python - how to label an additional axis / colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a simple plot of the Iris dataset, plotting sepal length against sepal width. I want to create a colobar next to this figure and label the colobar with ONLY 0, 1 and 2. I succeed in generating the plot and the colorbar, but the labelling of the colorbar doesn't work the way I want it to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets


# import the Iris-dataset from sklearn
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = np.array(iris.data)
labels = np.array(iris.target)


fig = plt.figure()
img = plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], c=labels, cmap='rainbow', edgecolor='k', s=50)

plt.xlabel("Sepal Length [cm]", fontname="Calibri", fontsize=14, labelpad=14)
plt.ylabel("Sepal Width [cm]", fontname="Calibri", fontsize=14, labelpad=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)

cax = fig.add_axes([0.93, 0.09, 0.02, 0.8])
cax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=12)
cax.set_yticks(ticks=[0, 1, 2], minor=False)
cax.set_yticklabels(labels=['0', '1', '2'], minor=False)

fig.colorbar(img, cax=cax, orientation="vertical")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Can somebody explain to me how to get rid of the labels that I don't want? I only want to see the 0, 1 and 2 on my colorbar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib discrete colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code a bit according to [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html) documentation and it did the trick:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from pylab import cm

# import the Iris-dataset from sklearn
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = np.array(iris.data)
labels = np.array(iris.target)


fig = plt.figure()
img = plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], c=labels, cmap='rainbow', edgecolor='k', s=50)

plt.xlabel("Sepal Length [cm]", fontname="Calibri", fontsize=14, labelpad=14)
plt.ylabel("Sepal Width [cm]", fontname="Calibri", fontsize=14, labelpad=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)

cax = fig.add_axes([0.93, 0.09, 0.02, 0.8])
cax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=12)
# cax.set_yticks(ticks=[0, 1, 2], minor=False)
# cax.set_yticklabels(labels=['0', '1', '2'], minor=False)

cbar = fig.colorbar(img, cax=cax, ticks=[0, 1, 2])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['0', '1', '2'])

# fig.colorbar(img, cax=cax, orientation="vertical")
plt.show()
```

resulting plot:

[image: outputplot]