# Scatter plot with more than 20 labels and different colors

Tags: python, plot, cluster-analysis, figure

I want to plot the result of a clustering with 40 clusters. I have this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
for i in labels:
    plt.scatter(df.iloc[cluster == i , 0] ,
                df.iloc[cluster == i , 1], label = i, alpha= 0.8)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),ncol = 2)
plt.show()
```

and the result is :
[image]
As you can see 20 colors are repeating. How can I assign 40 different colors to these clusters?

I've seen this link:
[Matplotlib color according to class labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487060/matplotlib-color-according-to-class-labels)

But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib color according to class labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487060/matplotlib-color-according-to-class-labels)

Comment: @ScottC I tried the cmap. But it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `c` parameter of the [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) function to specify the colour, like this:

#### Code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
for i in labels:
    plt.scatter(df.iloc[cluster == i , 0] , df.iloc[cluster == i , 1], label = i, alpha= 0.8, c=i, cmap='viridis')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),ncol = 2)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can specify your own colour list like this:

```
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'brown', 'pink', 'gray', 'olive', 'cyan', 'navy', 'teal', 'maroon', 'silver', 'tan', 'gold', 'purple', 'moccasin', 'bisque', 'wheat', 'peachpuff', 'navajowhite', 'salmon', 'crimson', 'palevioletred', 'darksalmon', 'lightcoral', 'hotpink', 'palegoldenrod', 'plum', 'darkkhaki', 'orchid', 'thistle', 'lightgray', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'lightskyblue', 'lightyellow', 'lavender', 'linen']

plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
for i in labels:
    plt.scatter(df.iloc[cluster == i , 0] , df.iloc[cluster == i , 1], label = i, alpha= 0.8, color=colors[i])
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),ncol = 2)
plt.show()
```